# Why does sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0]) give me the size of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

If I have an array as an argument in main

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

why will

```
sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])
```

always reliably give me the length of the array?

Comment: Maybe this is the size (in bytes) or the array divided by the size (in bytes) of an element of the array, which equals the number of elements. I'm just guessing -- I'm not a C++ guy.

Comment: It will only "reliably" give you the length if the length is 1. Both of your `sizeof` arguments are pointers.

Comment: `int main(int argc, *char argv[])` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't.

I probably got a bit carried away when writing this answer; it's too much of a language-lawyer approach to a fairly simple question. I'll add this quick summary which should be enough to answer the question. The pedantic and overly verbose version of the answer is below the horizontal line.

Given:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

`argv` isn't an array at all; it's a pointer. (C and C++ don't permit parameters of array type; something that looks like an array parameter is really a pointer parameter.) `argv` does point (at run time) to the first element of an array, but there's no information *in the declaration* about how big that array is. That's why we need the `argc` parameter to provide that information.

So `sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])` *doesn't* give you the number of elements in an array; it just divides the size of a pointer by the size of a pointer, which *probably* gives you `1`. (Why only "probably"? That's part of the overly pedantic answer below.)

Now if you define something explicitly as an array object:

```
int an_array[42];
```

you *can* use that idiom to compute the number of elements in the array:

```
sizeof an_array / sizeof an_array[0]
```

This yields `42`, the number of elements in the array. The way it works is (I think) fairly straightforward: it's the size in bytes of the whole array divided by the size in bytes of one of its elements.

But it works *only* for an actual array, not for something like `argv` that *looks* like an array but is really a pointer.

The relationship between arrays and pointers can be confusing. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) explains it very well, and most or all of it applies to both C and C++.

Now the long-winded pedantic explanation with too many digressions:

---

`argv` is a pointer, specifically a pointer to pointer to `char`.  As a parameter declaration (and *only* in that context), `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv`.

`sizeof (argv)` is the number of bytes in a `char**` pointer.

`sizeof (argv[0])` is the number of bytes in a `char*` pointer.

`sizeof (argv) / sizeof (argv[0])` is very likely to be 1 (assuming that `char*` and `char**` have the same size, which they do in most implementations).

Now for something that's been defined as an array object:

```
some_type an_array[COUNT];
```

that expression does work; this:

```
sizeof an_array / sizeof an_array[0]
```

does give you the number of elements in `an_array`, namely `COUNT`.  The reason for that should, I think, be fairly obvious. The number of bytes in an array is the number of bytes in one element of the array multiplied by the number of elements. So:

```
sizeof an_array == sizeof an_array[0] * COUNT
```

and, rearranging the terms:

```
sizeof an_array / sizeof an_array[0] == COUNT
```

Incidentally, `sizeof an_array[0]` can also be written as `sizeof *an_array`, due to the way the indexing operator is defined in C.

(Note that the `sizeof` operator doesn't require parentheses around its argument, if that argument is an expression such as an object name. The operand to `sizeof` is either an expression or a parenthesized type name. But if you prefer to always use parentheses with `sizeof`, you can do that.)

This is a common idiom for computing the number of elements in an array -- but it works only if you have the name of the array itself, not a pointer to its first element.

[The following applies to C. I believe it also applies to C++ (I initially didn't notice that the question is tagged C++, not C).]

In answer to a question raised in comments, no, `char*` and `char**` are not required to have the same size. The C standard's requirements on pointer representation are:

> A pointer to **void** shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers
>   to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers
>   to other types need not have the same representation or alignment
>   requirements.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.2.5p28.

The C++ standard has at least some some of this; section 3.9.2 [basic.compound] of the N3485 draft says:

> An object of type *cv* `void*` shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as *cv* `char*`.

I haven't found the corresponding text for the rest of what I quoted from the C standard.

On a word-addressed machine, a `char*` pointer could plausibly require more information to specify both a word and a byte within that word than is needed for a `char**` pointer, which only needs to specify an aligned word.

Comment: Aren't they required to have the same size? I think the only pointer that can be different is a function pointer, or a member function pointer.

Comment: They *have* to have the same size, don't they? Otherwise `(char*)(char**)(char*)p` could lose information...

Comment: The new common idiom for calculating the number of elements in an array *should* be `std::array<T, N>::size()` :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: It could. The C++ standard doesn't require your expression to have any meaningful result, or the representations to be compatible (eg: the implementation may enforce 4-byte alignment on `char**` values, and only 1-byte alignment on `char*` and could segfault when these are violated). The only requirement is that `void*` rules them all, so you can stuff any pointer-value into it and get it back unharmed.

Comment: @Mehrdad: No they don't have to have the same size.  The expression you listed is allowed to lose information, if `char*` has alignment restrictions.  OTOH `char** p; (char**)(char*)p` cannot lose information, because `char` never has alignment restrictions.

Comment: @jpalecek: `char` isn't allowed to have alignment restrictions either, so `char*` is just as feasible for a universal pointer type as `void*`, if a bit messier because of the need for explicit casts.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Can you give me a theoretical example in which the sizes of `char*` and `char**` are different? What could they be, for instance?

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm really wondering where I got that idea from then.

Comment: @Mehrdad: On systems that don't support unaligned access, a `char*` has to be placed on a multiple of 4, say.  Then the low two bits of a `char**` are always zero, and therefore don't even need to be stored.  On other systems, the pointers might be the same size, but `(char**)p` could mask off the lowest two bits, forcing them to zero.

Comment: @Keith: You cited the wrong document.  I think that section 5.2.10p7 of the C++ Standard leads to essentially the same conclusion, however.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're right; I've *partially* corrected that. I don't think 5.2.10p7 leads to the same conclusion, though (assuming that's [expr.reinterpret.cast]). A C++ `reinterpret_cast` acts like a C cast; a conversion from one pointer type to another may be non-trivial, doing more than just reinterpreting the representation. If there's a statement in the C++ standard that `struct foo*` and `struct bar*` must have the same representation, something that's explicitly stated in C, I haven't found it.

Comment: @Keith: I'm referring to this part specifically: "Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified."

Comment: Basically it leads to the conclusion that pointers to types with different alignment can have different ranges.  I don't see that the representation is ever required to be the same as long as casts hide the differences, since you can't directly observe the representation without breaking aliasing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Both C and C++ require `void*` and pointer-to-character types to have the same representation and alignment requirements. C also requires this for pointer-to-struct types and pointer-to-union types (which lets you operate on pointer-to-incomplete-struct types without knowing the full type). C++ probably *should* require the same thing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That doesn't make sense to me. If `struct S*` can be used *without* knowing the definition of `struct S`, then that means I can put **whatever** I want as the first (and only) member of `S`, and cast back and forth between the address of that member and `S*` without loss of information. And since `S` would have the same size as (and no padding before) its first and only member, doesn't this imply what you're saying is false -- i.e. that all bits in all pointers must be significant? (i.e. just put a pointer as the member.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think so.  An implementation could state that "every structure is at least aligned to a 4 byte boundary", so that `struct { char c; }` would have 3 bytes of padding.  The rule about casting between pointer to a structure and pointer to its first member has as precondition that member respects the structure's alignment, so it doesn't interact with this rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does my conclusion at least hold *if* you verify that the implementation always sets the size of a one-member struct to be equal to the size of its member?

Comment: I don't think so.  That might make all structure pointers store full precision, but primitive types could still have alignment requirements and smaller pointers, and the structure pointers would end up containing invariant trailing zeros, depending on the structure's actual alignment.

Comment: oops, I forgot to summon @Mehrdad with that last comment

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for summoning me back. :-) That sounds impossible -- if the structure pointer had trailing zeros but the address of its member did not, then casting both to `void*` and comparing them would return false. Doesn't that completely contradict the fact that a struct must have the same exact address as its first member?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29963/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-mehrdad)

Comment: To summarize the chat, the address of an aligned object has trailing zeros.  It's possible that those are explicitly stored in a `void*`, and implied but not stored in a more specific pointer type.  Casting from a reduced representation to `void*` would necessarily recreate those unstored zeros, probably by a bit shift.